# Search product will give nothing in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalogsearch, redirect-url, search-terms

I am facing an issue that whenever I searched a sku (the attribute is searchable - yes), no result found.
My catalogsearch_query has Null for that query string "redirect" column.

https://prnt.sc/mltdym

Suggest how the "redirect value" set for this table's entry.
The url is present in the product and url_rewrite table as well.

Product visibility is catalog,search.

When I manually hit the product URL it is working fine.

Comment: Did you re-index?

Answer (score 0):

You can set and edit redirects for any search keyword in the admin panel

```
Catalog -> Search Tearms
```

Documentation regarding this topic can be found [here on the oficial Magento site](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/search_seo/search-terms-new.html)